# Angular Material: Input with hint text and error text at the same time

Tags: angular, angular-material

I copied the Angular Material [email example](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown) exactly. It has hint text and error text. My issue is that the error text overrides the hint text. How do I keep the hint text there?

If I try and change it to a simple span tag it messes up the control.

Comment: Please provide your code, best would be to create a demo (plunker/stackblitz) that showcases your issue. I couldn't reproduce the issue, but then again I don't see your code, I just took the code from the angular material site. And yes, you say you copied it exactly, but there has to be some error in your code for it to behave like you explain.

Comment: @AJT_82 us the plunked from the official website. I told you I'm using that exact code.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you want? With `error text overrides the hint text`. How does it now behave? How do you want it to behave? When should the hint be shown?

Comment: I want the hint and the error text to show at the same time. Currently, as soon as the error text appears the hint disappears. i don't really know how else to describe that.

Comment: I have create an issue on angular material github, give it a thumb-up if also think it should be implemented: 
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/23459

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Angular Material `input` behavior follows the [Material Design guidelines on text fields](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout) which states:

> When input isn’t accepted, text fields can display an error message
> below the input line, with instructions on how to fix the error. Until
> the error is fixed, the error replaces the helper text.

You could add a custom error message container below the hint text using something like:

```html
<div class="text-danger margin-bottom-thin my-mat-hint">
    {{error}}<span>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Where `my-mat-hint` is defined as:

```css
.my-mat-hint {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

The full context of the Material Design documentation is provided below.

#### Helper text

> Helper text gives context about a field’s input, such as how the input
> will be used.
>
> It should be visible either persistently or only on focus.

[image: Helper text example]

#### Error message

> When input isn’t accepted, text fields can display an error message
> below the input line, with instructions on how to fix the error. Until
> the error is fixed, the error replaces the helper text.
>
> An error message should appear on a single line, if possible.

[image: Error message example]

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems the link has changed and I cant find this in any new documentation - but angular material is still implemented as such.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. The error message will overlap the Hint. Here is what I do to solve the issue. I hide the Hint via CSS when there is an error related to the field and when the error is fixed, the style is automatically removed and the Hint shows up intact.

The way this happens is that Angular adds a class "mat-form-field-invalid" for every input element that has an invalid state. So we will use the class name to hide/show the hint for the invalid element.

Here is example code to solve the problem:

**Form Field:**

```
<mat-form-field>

        <input matInput required
               formControlName="materialName"
               name="materialName"
               id="materialName"
               placeholder="Enter Material Name..."/>

        <mat-hint align="start">Min 1</mat-hint>

        <div class="error-message" *ngIf="error">Error</div>

</mat-form-field>
```

**CSS:**

***This will hide the Hint whenever there is an error for a form field:***

```
.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-hint {
    display: none;
}
```

***Show the Hint as well as the Error at the same time:***

If you would rather show the Hint as well as the Error at the same time, then we just need to do a single style tweak. Instead of hiding the hint, we just add a margin to it so that it aligns itself from a distance, when Error occurs. So here is the revised style:

```
.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-hint {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

***Caveat:*** Make sure that the Hint is placed within the `<mat-form-field></mat-form-field>` tags. If you place the Hint outside of these tags, then the above code won't work.

Good Luck!